# Google calendar service.events().list not returning events

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to get all the events from my calendar for specific time intervals, but I get a an empty list as result even when I have a meeting already booked. If I check, for instance, at 16:00, it results like I have no meetings even though I have a meeting booked at that exact time.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
import datetime 
from datetime import timedelta

t = datetime.datetime.strptime(t,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')

t = '2019-10-15T16:00:00'

start = t.isoformat() + 'Z'
end = t + timedelta(minutes=30)
end = end.isoformat() + 'Z'
pageToken=None
eventsResult = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=start, timeMax=end,
                                     maxResults=20, singleEvents=True, orderBy='startTime',
                                    pageToken=pageToken,).execute()



events = eventsResult.get('items', [])
if not events:
    print(str(start) + str(end) + ' No upcoming events found.')
```

The event is visible from my primary calendar, is not private and is marked as busy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue!

The problem was that it was using a different time in the same timezone (winter time instead of summer time), and that was affecting the results.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use service account for the credential ?

AFAIK service account has it's own calendar. So, when you access it using **Primary**, it will show service account calendar event, not your calendar.

If you want to see your event, i think you need to share your own calendar with service account (using client_email), then try to change **calendarId** with your own email.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a service account but I was specifying the calendarId for my own email, I used primary just to give a reproducible example. The problem was a poor handling of the timezone (which was not accounting for summer time).